# JPA Collection of Primary Keys

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, primary-key, one-to-many

I am looking to create a collection of primary keys (effectively a one-to-many relationship of entity keys without resolving the referenced entity).

For example,

```
@Entity
public class BigObject {
   @EmbeddedId
   private BigObjectId id;
   // lots of other stuff
}

@Embeddable
public class BigObjectId {
    //fields here
}

@Entity
public class Referrer {
   // This won't work since BigObjectId is an embeddable. I would like a join table
   // REFERRER_BIGOBJECTS with a REFERRER_ID PK foreign key and a BIGOBJECT_ID PK
   // foreign key.
   @OneToMany
   private Set<BigObjectId> bigObjectIds;
}
```

I realize this seems to defeat the purpose of ORM, but it is beneficial to be able to iterate through the big objects without having to resolve them in their entirety (the embedded ID object is used other places in the system). Is there a a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use an ElementCollection mapping.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection#Basic_Collections

Comment: The ElementCollection mapping will allow a collection of BigObjectIds, but it will not allow those to be foreign keys, and there is no ability to specify a cascade action. If that is the best that is available, I can try to manage ensuring consistency on my own...